# How does the design of JavaBeans square with information hiding?

Tags: javabeans, principles, information-hiding

Two semesters ago, I had a professor who said:

> Some of you have been told to always include setter and getter methods for all private instance variables. I say that this breaks information hiding, and often results in systems where invariants cannot be enforced.

Now, that sounds right to me.  But isn't including those kinds of setters/getters a core part of creating JavaBeans?  If so, why?  If not, what am I misunderstanding about JavaBeans?

Comment: Quick answer: the person who told me "JavaBeans require getters and setters for everything" was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters and setters are not required in a Java Bean class. All that's required is that the class must be public, it must have a public no argument constructor and it must implement Serializable. However, in order for variables to be discovered automatically when your bean is used you must provide getters and setters following a standard naming convention (getVarname, setVarname...).

In any case, you want to make externally visible only the variables that have a business being seen outside your class.

Answer (score 1):

Your professor is correct. You do not want to blindly create getters and setters for all instance variables. You want to create them where they are required.

If you have a `BankAccount` class with a `balance` instance variable, creating getters and setters for it makes sense if you want to be able to check and set the balance.

Even here there is information hiding - in the form of encapsulating the implementation. The getter "`double getBalance()`" could simply return the value of the underlying instance variable if it is a `double`, or it could be returning a value derived from a `BigDecimal` if that is the implementation choice for the variable, or it could be calling a remote web service and returning the result. So, the getter/setter still allows for the implementation to vary and thus does not violate encapsulation (and by extension, neither do JavaBeans).

What JavaBeans do for you is define an interface (`getXXX(), setXXX()`) for getting and setting "properties", attributes of a class that users would typically want to examine or change. If your class has information that is not considered a "property", there is no need to expose it. For example, let's say the `BankAccount` class has an instance variable used for validating withdrawals. If the client does not need access or modify this, there is no point in creating a getter or setter for it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read [Why getter and setter methods are evil](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2003/jw-0905-toolbox.html):

> You might object by saying, "But what
>   about JavaBeans?" What about them? You
>   can certainly build JavaBeans without
>   getters and setters. The
>   `BeanCustomizer`, `BeanInfo`, and
>   `BeanDescriptor` classes all exist for
>   exactly this purpose. The JavaBean
>   spec designers threw the getter/setter
>   idiom into the picture because they
>   thought it would be an easy way to
>   quickly make a bean—something you can
>   do while you're learning how to do it
>   right. Unfortunately, nobody did that.
>
> Accessors were created solely as a way
>   to tag certain properties so a
>   UI-builder program or equivalent could
>   identify them. You aren't supposed to
>   call these methods yourself. They
>   exist for an automated tool to use.
>   This tool uses the introspection APIs
>   in the `Class` class to find the methods
>   and extrapolate the existence of
>   certain properties from the method
>   names. In practice, this
>   introspection-based idiom hasn't
>   worked out. It's made the code vastly
>   too complicated and procedural.
>   Programmers who don't understand data
>   abstraction actually call the
>   accessors, and as a consequence, the
>   code is less maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually quite simple, you expose setters/getters for the variables you need to make visible externally, and you don't expose setters/getters for variables noone else have any business knowing about.